# What the reason for not taking contribution of gravity when a wave is propagating?

Tags: waves, string

Suppose a wave is being transmitted from one end of rope to other , for small amplitudes the wave speed is √T/u , suppose now that amplitudes of wave are not small and that gravity is also need to be considered , what change will take place in the speed and linear mass density when gravity consideration is need to be taken and why it was neglected in most scenarios?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard derivation of the one-dimensional wave equation assumes that the mass per unit length of the string is the same along its length and that gravity does not vary significantly from the lowest point of the wave to the highest. These are reasonable approximations in many common scenarios. They give rise to a linear partial differential equation, which can be solved analytically using methods such as Fourier analysis.

If these assumptions are not valid then you will end up with a non-linear PDE which is unlikely to have nice neat analytical solutions for general boundary conditions.